# How to use self as the DataContext in a Silverlight MVVM application?

Tags: binding, silverlight-4.0, mvvm, datacontext

In my Silverlight MVVM application, in the code-behind of a view, I set the DataContext to a viewmodel as such:

```
this.DataContext = new MyViewModel();
```

However, I need to bind one control in the view to another in the same view. So, I need to set the DataContext of the control where I'm adding the binding to the view itself.

After browsing around, it seems like the definitive way of doing this in **WPF** is by adding:

```
DataContext="{Binding  
    RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,  
    AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}
```

to the control.

However the AncestorType property does not exist in Silverlight 4. Is there an equivalent, definitive line of code that is used for this scenario in **Silverlight**? I haven't run into any website or answer that shows the best practice for this.

This may help me answer an [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8855639/binding-a-usercontrol-to-a-custom-busyindicator-control) where I am trying to bind a custom control and property within a view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you explain what do you want to do?

Probably you can use `ElementName` from `Binding` [class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.elementname.aspx)

Here is a sample example from [msdn page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742167.aspx):

```
<Border Margin="10" BorderBrush="Silver" BorderThickness="3" Padding="8">
  <DockPanel>
    <TextBlock>Choose a Color:</TextBlock>
    <ComboBox Name="myComboBox" SelectedIndex="0">
      <ComboBoxItem>Green</ComboBoxItem>
      <ComboBoxItem>Blue</ComboBoxItem>
      <ComboBoxItem>Red</ComboBoxItem>
    </ComboBox>
    <Canvas>
      <Canvas.Background>
        <Binding ElementName="myComboBox" Path="SelectedItem.Content"/>
      </Canvas.Background>
    </Canvas>
  </DockPanel>
</Border>
```

Comment: The problem is I want to bind to a control, not just a property of a control. I created my own control that extends BusyIndicator to have an extra property of type Control. The goal is when the BusyIndicator loses focus I call the Focus() command on the Control I am binding to. However I am not able to set a control to my extra property in the XAML and thought it was related to the DataContext. See my related [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8855639/binding-a-usercontrol-to-a-custom-busyindicator-control).

Comment: Oh, I see - sorry, but I still don't fully understand your problem.