# how to set focus for control in code for Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight-4.0

How to set focus for silverlight control in code? For example, I have a user control MyControl, in code, I want to do something like:

```
MyControl.GetFocus();
```

but there is no function GetFocus(), only event GotFocus.

How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Focus().

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc903954(v=vs.95).aspx

also look at this question - [How Do I Give a Textbox Focus in Silverlight?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/124649/how-do-i-give-a-textbox-focus-in-silverlight)