# I cannot get this textbox to get focus when the application first starts

Tags: c#, silverlight

...in Silverlight. No tags in the title, and all that. I'm using Silverlight 4 on Chrome, though I've tried it on IE too. I've tried:

```
System.Windows.Browser.HtmlPage.Plugin.Focus();
this.Focus();
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => { textBox_username.Focus(); });
```

And various combinations thereof (as suggested by a similar thread), as well as a separate method that was attached to the form loaded event. The above gets me the closest, since clicking anywhere on the page gives my textbox focus, like the plugin isn't getting focus still. Could be because this is the first window viewed?

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/124649/how-do-i-give-a-textbox-focus-in-silverlight

Comment: @Ajay I said in my question that I tried that already

Answer (score 0):

I dont think that was because the first window viewed. try to put `this.Focus();` after your Dispatcher you set it false;

Answer (score 0):

Change your code similar to below

```
public partial class MainPage : UserControl
```

{

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.Loaded += MainPage_Loaded;
}

void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    System.Windows.Browser.HtmlPage.Plugin.Focus();
    txtBox.UpdateLayout();
    txtBox.Focus();
}
```

}