# Windows Phone close popup if tap anywhere else

Tags: c#, popup, windows-phone

I have a Windows Phone app that I'm currently developing, and my share button opens a small popup with several options, using the following code:

```
       private void share_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e) 
    {

        Popup share= new Popup();
        share.Child = new sharePopup();
        share.IsOpen = true;
        share.VerticalOffset = 30;
        share.HorizontalOffset = 0;
    }
```

Now, this Popup has a 'close' button, but if I don't tap it, and instead tap another button on the previous, still visible page, the popup stays in place, even after moving to a new page. I HAVE to click on 'close' for the popup to go away.

What I'm looking for is a way for the popup to close if I tap anywhere outside of the popup itself. Is there a predefined method to do this? If not, what ways could I go at it?

Thanks in advance

EDIT: Here's the c# code for the pop-up

```
      public partial class sharePopup : UserControl
{
    public sharePopup()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {            
        Popup mensaje = this.Parent as Popup;
        mensaje.IsOpen = false;
    }
      private void UserControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Focus();
    }

    private void UserControl_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Popup mensaje = this.Parent as Popup;
        mensaje.IsOpen = false;
    }
}
```

}

The XAML for the popup only contains size, color and button definitions:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MSPinTrainingApp.sharePopup"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
d:DesignHeight="480" d:DesignWidth="480"
Width="480" Height="200" >

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" LostFocus="LayoutRoot_LostFocus">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.Background>
        <SolidColorBrush Color="{StaticResource PhoneChromeColor}"/>
    </Grid.Background>
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
               Margin="3" x:Name="txtMensaje" Text="Compartir:" LostFocus="txtMensaje_LostFocus" />
    <Image Margin="70,60,335,62" Source="appbar.email.hardedge.png" Stretch="Fill" Tap="Image_Tap_1"/>
    <Image Margin="200,60,200,62" Source="appbar.facebook.png" Stretch="Fill" Tap="Image_Tap_2"/>
    <Image Margin="335,60,70,62" Source="appbar.twitter.bird.png" Stretch="Fill" Tap="Image_Tap_3"/>
    <Image Margin="430,-12,11,134" Source="/appbar.close.png" Width="50" Tap="Image_Tap_4"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: We would need to see the XAML, but it looks like you're setting the LostFocus event on a text box. Are you making the text box get focus wen the popup is displayed? If not, then LostFocus will not be called on that control.

Comment: You're right, that's my mistake... Posting the XAML shortly.

Comment: OK. The rest of my earlier comment is unanswered though. Are you setting focus to txtMensaje? See this for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/124649

Comment: No, I wasn't, and I removed that txtMensaje_LostFocus. Using that other question you posted, I added a UserControl_Loaded(...) method with this.Focus() in it, and a UserControl_LostFocus(...) with code for closing the popup, but still nothing.

Comment: What are you seeing in the debugger? Alos, I would try to continue with the text box idea and setting the focus to it explicitly. LostFocus should get called on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much failed experimentation and looking around the web, I came upon the Coding4Fun toolkit, and was able to make a working popup with its MessagePrompt. 
The toolkit is available at http://coding4fun.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 6):

I found helpful just set `IsLightDismissEnabled="True"` when you declare your `Popup` control.
[MSDN description](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.primitives.popup.islightdismissenabled)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of playing with "lost focus", which does not work in all cases (e.g if you have textboxes or other focusable controls in Popup). I recommend dismissing popup, by detecting tap in root visual:

```
            Application.Current.RootVisual.Tap += (s, e) =>
            {
                popup.IsOpen = false;
            };
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try handling the [LostFocus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.lostfocus%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) event of the UIElement. When your OnLostFocus handler is called within the popup, then close the popup (close itself).

Comment: That seems like a step in the right direction, but I would need to first move focus from the main page to the popup when clicking the share button... I'm unfamiliar with how to do this, could you possibly provide a link or anything to it?

Comment: The focus should automatically go to the top-most UIElement. In your case it should be the popup.

Comment: I see. I added a popup_LostFocus method inside the sharePopup.xaml.cs control telling it to close the popup, but it does nothing as is

Comment: @iVikD - Should be as simple as setting the `Focus` property.  Unless you try.....of course....

Comment: We may need to see more code to help. Your XAML and the handler etc.

Comment: @PaulSasik alright, I'll update the question with some more code.

Comment: LostFocus event is not triggering.