# Functions like Focus() and properties like Focusable not available for silverlight, only .NET?

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-5.0, xna-4.0

Short version: Solutions like the following: [How Do I Give a Textbox Focus in Silverlight?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/124649/how-do-i-give-a-textbox-focus-in-silverlight)

Don't seem to work because functions like Focus and properties like Focusable DON'T EXIST for silverlight and only exist for .net apparently.

Background/Long Version: So I've been trying to get my XNA game to work on silverlight. Porting it was a nightmare but I managed to do it somehow. Currently I want to use ViewBox's so my game is as big as a players browser instead of a set size. When I tried to do it, it VISUALLY worked, but it was impossible to send any keyboard commands to the game. I'm pretty sure its preventing me from focusing it. When I google how to give focus, it gives me links like these where people are saying to use functions like .focus() which DON'T EXIST on silverlight 5 only .NET apparently. For example go here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.control(v=vs.110).aspx 
It shows the .NET 4.5 version. If you change it to silverlight at the top, all the nice functions and settings disappear. Am I missing something here? How do I access the .Net versions of these classes in silverlight? If its not possible why are all those answers mentioned above use Focus() etc?

Comment: Maybe you looked too hastily. Look again, the method `Focus()` is available for `Control` and all derived types. The properties `Focusable` and `IsFocused` are not available, but you can implement them as `ExtensionMethods` and use them as if they were available.

Comment: ...and there is a method `IsKeyboardFocusable()` you might be able to use, available via [automationpeer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.automation.peers.automationpeer%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

Comment: The derived types don't seem to useful for trying to run a game (text box, calendar etc..). What are extension methods exactly and how would I implement them? I'll try tinkering with automationpeer, are there examples for it that you know of? Thanks!

Comment: What is your top level Element of your SilverlightApplication? The one that hosts the `ViewBox` you mentioned. Isn't it derived from `Control` or `UserControl`? You can derive your own types (hosting your game's viewport) from `Control`.

Comment: Example `ExtensionMethod` usage: `if (myControl.IsFocused()) {...}` and definition somewhere else: `public static class MyControlExtensions { public static bool IsFocused(this Control control){ return ...FocusManager...magic... }}`

Comment: I guess you are right, it is from control (the control page didn't list it my bad). I've never made a derived class from a silverlight class before what does that involve (I did a lot of XNA but barely any silverlight). Also For some reason (unrelated), I get a purple screen when I load my XNA game, I can sometimes screw with the xaml code and move the purple square away but it limits what I can do. Its actually a HUGE source of annoyance for me and I don't understand it at all, but I don't think many people are using silver light with XNA because googling gives me nothing.

Comment: I just saw your example comment I'll try stuff out.

Comment: By the way just to validate my original question, Viewbox (a control derivative) does NOT have a focus() method. I still don't understand how other people are using that.

Comment: Wow, you are quick to judge... and walk the developer earth with a bag full of wrong assumptions and conclusions. No, your Viewbox is no Control; Yes, other people are using it, maybe they place it inside a ViewboxHost derived from UserControl and can easily handle Keyboard input from there. Dunno.

Comment: I make many mentions that I don't know that much, why are you being rude? Thanks for the help though.

Comment: Sorry for my rude answer. Was a bit too heavy a response.

Comment: No problem, thanks for the help. I found a workaround to giving the view box focus, instead I just give a grid focus(which worked automatically) and put the grid inside the view box. I'll probably run into this again later and come back to your post, or get similar issues.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming C#...

On your silverlight page, select yourPage_Created from write code menu

Add the following:

```
partial void YourPage_Created() // this line should be autogenerated
{
this.FindControl("YourControl").ControlAvailable += YourFieldAvailable;
}

private void YourFieldAvailable(object sender, ControlAvailableArguments e)
{
((System.Windows.Controls.Control)e.Control).GotFocus += YourRoutine;
}

private void YourRoutine(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
{
// do your focus specific code in here
}
```

You will now have a custom focus event for the specified control.
Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks for the help this is really frustrating me. But doesn't this just add an event handler for when you get focus? I was probably unclear in my post, I was hoping to find a way to give the ViewBox focus (mainly keyboard focus), not do stuff after it got focus.

Comment: In that case, try: this.FindControl("YourControl").Focus() in the method you wish to have give focus to your viewbox. If you want contol 1 gaining focus to pass focus to contol 2, you would use the code above with the this.FindControl("YourControl").Focus()  in 'YourRoutine'

Comment: Those don't seem to be working for me in silverlight. So I tried doing .FindControl and even in a grid control object it didn't have the function. Even worse the Focus() function doesn't seem to exist for the default viewbox and grid classes. Its okay, I found a very weird workaround of just putting my drawing surface inside a grid, which is inside a view box. And just having the grid which DOES seem to be focusable by default, retrieve the keyboard input and attach to the drawingsurface game.