# Silverlight TextBox cant get focus

Tags: silverlight, textbox, focus

I have several controls in my silverlight view including telerik and my own controls(Custom controls).in this view there is a TextBox called **AppointmentSubject** which needs to be focused when i open this view.this textbox is also a custom control.I did following thing inside the **View_Loaded** method.

```
    System.Windows.Browser.HtmlPage.Plugin.Focus();
    //TextBoxName.Focus()
    AppointmentSubject.Focus();
```

But AppointmentSubject only gets focused when i open the view second time.Any idea how i achieve it right first time?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How Do I Give a Textbox Focus in Silverlight?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/124649/how-do-i-give-a-textbox-focus-in-silverlight)

Comment: If you have other controls that grab focus the very moment they loaded, it could well be one of those other controls grabs it from your TextBox. I always tell people to **not** grab focus _onLoaded_ because of this. Better to place `foo.Focus()` in code that is triggering the view creation for `foo` in the first place.